# Upgrading PostgreSQL via Homebrew

Tags: bash, postgresql, homebrew

I'm attempting to update PostgreSQL from my system's version (9.1.5) to the latest release (9.2.3). I've followed the directions on this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql) and am encountering issues.

After installing psql via `brew install postgresql` I receive successful confirmation of the installation:

`Summary /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.3: 2824 files, 39M, built in 2.3 minutes`

I then init the database via

`initdb /usr/local/var/postgres -E utf8`

And start the database with

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l logfile start`

However, after running `which psql` the path has not changed from the system's default version:

`/usr/bin/psql`

Nor has the version number: `psql --version`

`psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.5`

I have a hunch this may have something to do with my bash profile. Has anyone else encountered similar errors?

Please note, I am running Homebrew v0.9.4 on Mountain Lion v10.8.3

Comment: This appears to be an ever-recurring topic. It seems the osx-packagers have screwed up, and failed to remove the old psql binary in /usr/bin. Try renaming it (`cd /usr/bin; mv psql psql.OLD`) and if /usr/local/var/postgres is in your PATH and contains a psql binary it will be found. If it is not found, you'll need to download and install it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved the issue by editing `/etc/paths` and moving `/usr/local/bin` above `/usr/bin` in the file.