# Strange issue with upgrading bash in Yosemite using Homebrew

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm running OS X Yosemite. I need to use associative arrays in bash so I decided to use Homebrew to upgrade bash to 4.x. I performed the following steps:

1. `brew install bash`
2. I then added `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/etc/shells` and rebooted for good measure.
3. `chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash`
4. For good measure, I logged out and logged back in, though a simple Terminal restart would probably have sufficed.

When I open Terminal, things seem to be fine. If I say `$SHELL --version` I get `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0)`. Unfortunately, if I say `echo $BASH_VERSION` I get `3.2.53(1)-release`. Also, I can't seem to use any of the advanced features of Bash 4.x, like associative arrays, e.g., `declare -A foo` says `-bash: declare: -A: invalid option`.

Interestingly, `echo $0` says `-bash`.

What's going on here? How do I get my associative arrays?

Comment: What says *which bash*?

Comment: Looks like: http://superuser.com/questions/484924/bash-upgrade-on-mac-osx?rq=1 or http://superuser.com/questions/570433/upgrading-postgresql-via-homebrew?rq=1

Comment: @tfb785 `which bash` gives `/usr/local/bin/bash`.

Comment: @tfb785 Also, `/etc/paths` has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin`, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue, and it turned out to be with the my `#!` path.  Check to make sure you are not pointing it at:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

but at:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
```

If you want to continue to use `#!/bin/bash` at the top, you might want instead do:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/bash /bin/bash
```

Update:

If your `$PATH` has `/url/local/bin` before `/bin` and `/usr/bin` you can just do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

for a solution that is less specific to the OS X/Homebrew setup.